# Layered deployments with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am new to Terraform  so not even sure something like this is possible.  As an example, lets say I have a template that deploys an Azure resource group and a key vault in it.  And then lets say I have another template that deploys a virtual machine into the same resource group.  Is it possible to do a destroy with the virtual machine template without destroying the key vault and resource group?  We are trying to compartmentalize the parts of a large solution without having to put it all in a single template and we want to be able to manage each piece separately without affecting other pieces.

On a related note...we are storing state files in an Azure storage account.  If we breakup our deployment into multiple compartmentalized deployments...should each deployment have its own state file or should they all use the same state file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For larger systems it is common to split infrastructure across multiple separate *configurations* and apply each of them separately. This is a separate idea from (and complimentary to) using shared *modules*: modules allow a number of different configurations to have their own separate "copy" of a particular set of infrastructure, while the patterns described below allow an object managed by one configuration to be passed *by reference* to another.

If some configurations will depend on the results of other configurations, it's necessary to store these results in some data store that can be written to by its producer and read from by its consumer. In an environment where the Terraform state is stored remotely and readable broadly, [the `terraform_remote_state` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) is a common way to get started:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "resource_group" {
  # The settings here should match the "backend" settings in the
  # configuration that manages the network resources.
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "mycompany-terraform-states"
    region = "us-east-1"
    key    = "azure-resource-group/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.resource_group.resource_group_name}"
  # ... etc ...
}
```

The `resource_group_name` attribute exported by the `terraform_remote_state` data source in this example assumes that a value of that name was exposed by the configuration that manages the resource group using an [output](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html).

This decouples the two configurations so that they have an entirely separate lifecycle. You first `terraform apply` in the configuration that creates the resource group, and then `terraform apply` in the configuration that contains the `terraform_remote_state` data resource shown above. You can then apply that latter configuration as many times as you like without risk to the shared resource group or key vault.

---

While the `terraform_remote_state` data source is quick to get started with for any organization already using [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) (which is recommended), some organizations prefer to decouple configurations further by introducing an intermediate data store like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), which then allows data to be passed between configurations more explicitly.

To do this, the "producing" configuration (the one that manages your resource group) publishes the necessary information about what it created into Consul at a well-known location, using [the `consul_key_prefix` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/consul/r/key_prefix.html):

```
resource "consul_key_prefix" "example" {
  path_prefix = "shared/resource_group/"
  subkeys = {
    name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
    id   = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.id}"
  }

resource "consul_key_prefix" "example" {
  path_prefix = "shared/key_vault/"
  subkeys = {
    name = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.name}"
    id   = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
    uri  = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.uri}"
  }
}
```

The separate configuration(s) that use the centrally-managed resource group and key vault would then read it using [the `consul_keys` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/consul/d/keys.html):

```
data "consul_keys" "example" {
  key {
    name = "resource_group_name"
    path = "shared/resource_group/name"
  }
  key {
    name = "key_vault_name"
    path = "shared/key_vault/name"
  }
  key {
    name = "key_vault_uri"
    path = "shared/key_vault/uri"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "${data.consul_keys.example.var.resource_group_name}"
  # ... etc ...
}
```

In return for the additional complexity of running another service to store these intermediate values, the two configurations now know nothing about each other apart from the agreed-upon naming scheme for keys within Consul, which gives flexibility if, for example, in future you decide to refactor these Terraform configurations so that the key vault has its own separate configuration too. Using a *generic* data store like Consul also potentially makes this data available to the applications themselves, e.g. via [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template).

Consul is just one example of a data store that happens to already be well-supported in Terraform. It's also possible to achieve similar results using any other data store that Terraform can both read and write. For example, you could even store values in `TXT` records in [a DNS zone](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/dns_zone.html) and use [the DNS provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/dns/d/dns_txt_record_set.html) to read, as an "outside the box" solution that avoids running an additional service.

---

As usual, there is a tradeoff to be made here between simplicity (with "everything in one configuration" being the simplest possible) and flexibility (with a separate configuration store), so you'll need to evaluate which of these approaches is the best fit for your situation.

As some additional context: I've documented [a pattern I used successfully](http://apparently.me.uk/terraform-environment-application-pattern/) for a moderate-complexity system. In that case we used a mixture of Consul and DNS to create an "environment" abstraction that allowed us to deploy the same applications separately for a staging environment, production, etc. The exact technologies used are less important than the pattern, though. That approach won't apply exactly to all other situations, but hopefully there are some ideas in there to help others think about how to best make use of Terraform in their environment.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such helpful detail

Comment: Terragrunt does this pretty well, though it does not separate by layers but "components / moduels" that are specific to your product

Comment: I'm wondering if and then how the options you describe above prevent Terraform from deleting another project's infrastructure. It seems you've described how we can "share data" between configurations, but Terraform will delete resources that are not specified in a configuration. For example, if project 1 creates an S3 bucket, and project 2 creates another S3 bucket, running `terraform apply` on project 1 may attempt to delete project 2's S3 bucket because it is not specified in project 1's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy specific resources using `terraform destroy -target path.to.resource`. [Docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/destroy.html)

Different parts of a large solution can be split up into [modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html), these modules do not even have to be part of the same codebase and can be referenced remotely. Depending on your solution you may want to break up your deployments into modules and reference them from a "master" state file that contains everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Still trying to get my head wrapped around your module approach.  I have tried using a couple of modules from the repository but have had 0 luck with them so I have just been deploying stuff writing my own templates with resources.  This is one of the things I dislike about Terraform so far is that the documentation is weak in areas.  The documentation on destroy that you linked does not give me any insight into using it the way you referenced.